# How can I make NSTableView update itself for NSSystemColorsDidChange?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsnotificationcenter

When I change the system highlight color in the System Preferences, most Cocoa controls (like NSTextField) in all applications automatically update their own displays to use the new color.

NSTableView, however, does not.  It seems stuck with the highlight color that was in use when the application was launched.

Is there any way to work around this?  I can add an observer in my NSWindow for NSSystemColorsDidChange, and it is called when I change the system color, but what should I do with it?  The obvious things, like:

```
contentView?.needsDisplay = true
```

or:

```
viewsNeedDisplay = true
```

don't seem to do anything.

Comment: I tried this and the selection color of my table view changes with the system color. The selection color of the table views in the Finder doesn't always change. Switching back and forth to another window can fix the color.

Comment: `setSelectionHighlightStyle` does `reloadData`, `selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` and `setNeedsDisplay:`.

Comment: Strange.  Switching windows doesn't help for me, nor even causing the controller to be reloaded.  I wonder what is going on with mine that's making it behave differently.  I can confirm that the Finder is the same: it doesn't seem to get the new color, at all.

Comment: Those flags don't seem to help me.  I'm already doing things that would cause it to reload data and request redisplay (like unloading/reloading the controller/xib, and recomputing the data it's displaying).  And the Finder is suffering from this, too, so it's (probably) not just something crazy I'm doing.  It really seems to be caching the highlight color inside NSTableView somewhere.

Comment: (I've filed a radar on it.)